# Granting Secure Access from one website to another

Tags: asp.net, security

I'm really just looking to see how much folly is in the below suggestion from a security perspective.

I have two websites. One is an administration portal and the other is a members portal.

Within the administration portal administrators can retrieve a listing of members and I need to offer the ability for administrators to login to the member portal without having to enter the members login credentials.

Both are separate websites within IIS and for this discussion lets say they are on different servers.

Both websites access the same SQL Server database.

I was thinking that I could on the administrator clicking a "Login as Member" link create a random code string and save this to the database along with the member number.

I could then pass the code and member number to the member portal as query string parameters.

The member portal then read in these values and checks them in the database to verify that the code string exists and if so that it matches the member number also being passed. I could then login the member and set a flag in the database to set the code as being used and therefore invalid for future requests.

I'm thinking to bypass this a hacker would need to successfully guess the random code and pass that to the page alongside the corresponding member number for that code and for that combination to be marked as unused in the database.

This would seem to be unlikely given that only seconds will pass between the code being generated and the code being used.

If necessary I could always check the IP address of the request as users of the administration portal all share the same fixed IP address.

So do you think the above would stand up to scrutiny on a security review or will I need to go down the SSO route?

Comment: What type of security review?  Is there financial, medical, social security numbers, etc. accessible after login?  If you use a short-lived GUID and also are checking the IP address, that would be more secure than most of the password recovery methods that send a code to an email address.  Also, whether it's secure enough or not depends on how secure the environment is where the administrators are.  Do they lock their desktops when they are away from their desks?  Is access to the building controlled? Etc.  IT security relies on a lot of physical security...

Comment: Also, it may be assumed, but are you planning to use HTTPS?

Comment: Thanks Tony - Yes HTTPS would be used and for this discussion I'm looking to determine whether the method proposed would be deemed secure presuming other elements are secure such as administrators locking computers, building controls etc.

Comment: are the sites already live? What kind of authentication are you using? Do both sites utilize SSL?

Comment: Sites are in development. Both will use SSL and session based authentication will be used.

Comment: Is this a custom authentication provider? Or a framework like Classic, Simple, or Identity?

Comment: Basically authenticating user credentials against a database and then setting and subsequently checking for session variables.

Comment: So you have implemented you own password encryption, cookie factory, and http handlers for authentication?

Comment: Something similar to http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ca9151/securing-login-page-and-maintaining-single-session-per-user/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is very sound. I can confirm because I have implemented just such a solution for just such a reason. We analyzed the options and exposure. And after implementation, our application passed a  **[PCI Complaince Audit](http://www.compliance101.com/pci-compliance/pci-compliance-audit/)**.

**Reasons:**

- **SSL is Esential!** protects against sniffers. Essential. Without Encryption, sniffers could detect your GUID and may have a window to use it)
- As Tony pointed out, **the GUID is effectively unguessable**.
- Guid **Tokens** expiring should **expire within 24 hours**.

**Suggestions:**

- Checking against IP is good. But don't be fooled into a feeling of security from it. Anyone can *fake IP's in headers*. To be Secure against **XSS** and **CSRF** by using **[AntiForgery tokens](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)**.

The AntiForgery token is a cookie that populates your HTTPHeaders with **__RequestVerificationToken** which is almost as hard to guess as your GUID.

- Consider using an established Authentication framework like  [.NET Identity 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics) and multitenancy.

An established framework takes the burden of encrypting your passwords. MS Frameworks like ***Simple Membership*** and ***Identity*** integrate into modern ASP.NET frameworks and give you very strong base of functionality to lean on.

If you're using an old framework like classic ASP or .NET 2.0, the  [classic Membership Provider](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) is more appropriate.

If you are creating new ***MVC 5*** applications utilizing ***Entity Framework***, I strongly suggest using ***Identity 2.1***.

- Consider Mult-Tenancy. While there is nothing wrong with your solution, if Admins and users shared Membership Provider, your solution would be cleaner. An admin could log into the main site and "get" the token from the DB. Then no exposure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the use of HTTPS and adequate physical and IT security processes and procedures in place for the administrators, this method should be adequate.  It is more secure than most financial website password resets, which typically only require a compromised email account and some personal information to reset the password.  If you check the IP address range of the originating client request as well, a hacker would have had to already have access to your systems or network.  Also, if you make the code a GUID, it would be (pragmatically speaking) impossible for someone to guess.

You could add a layer of checking for hack attempts by storing a record in the database each time this event occurs (or at least each it fails due to a bad key), and each time it occurs run a check to see if it is happening too often (like 100 times in the past hour, or something--the right number depends on how often you expect it to happen).  If it's happening too often, then have it send an alert to IT personnel and revert so that the user has to enter their credentials manually.

Disclaimer: I am not a security expert by any means, so I'll gladly defer to anyone claiming such status.  I'm weighing in here due to a lack of answers.

Comment: Very useful and thanks for getting the ball rolling in terms of responses

Comment: Very good points. The part about checking for users "fishing" for keys is an interesting question. Repeated hits to your site by unauthorized parties, should be treated as DOS attack. Sinister problem.